# How to recover from Jenkins server failure using slaves?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

I have a Jenkins server that failed due to a kernel panic. Does Jenkins save job configurations on its slave servers? I'm hoping to try to recover from server going down.

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins only stores job configurations on the Jenkins master server.
Jenkins slaves are pretty much "dumb clients".

You should backup your master.